# Does the :is() pseudo class support a combinator for the second element in an adjacent sibling expression?

Tags: css, css-selectors

When writing CSS code for my `userChrome.css` in Firefox I encountered a problem when using the `:is()` pseudo class to shorten my adjacent sibling combinator expression.

The following code does NOT work for the second element inside `:is()`, that is  `#tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox-periphery > #tabs-newtab-button`.

```
#tabbrowser-tabs:not([overflow]) .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected], [multiselected]) + :is(.tabbrowser-tab:not([selected], [multiselected]), #tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox-periphery > #tabs-newtab-button) {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, .2) !important;
}
```

However, `:is()` works when removing `> #tabs-newtab-button`. It will then select the element `#tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox-periphery`.

And, it works, when not using the `:is()` pseudo class like this:

```
#tabbrowser-tabs:not([overflow]) .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected], [multiselected]) + .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected], [multiselected]),
#tabbrowser-tabs:not([overflow]) .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected], [multiselected]) + #tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox-periphery > #tabs-newtab-button {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, .2) !important;
}
```

My question: Is this expected behavior or is it a bug in the implementation of the `:is()` pseudo class in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both selectors aren't the same. Here is a simplified version to understand:

```css
a + b > c {
  color: red;
}

a + :is(b > c) {
  font-size: 500px; /* this will not have any effecy*/
}
```

```html
<a></a>
<b><c>text</c><b>
```

The second case is equivalent to `a + *:is(b > c)` so you will select any element sibling to the `a` that **is** a `c` element having a direct parent `b`

```css
a + b > c {
  color: red; /* this will not have any effecy*/
}

a + :is(b > c) {
  font-size: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<b>
<a></a>
<c>text</c>
</b>
```

Comment: That’s it! I couldn’t see it.